# Better way of setting input scope on text box in WP7

Tags: c#

This works but there must be a better way:

```
txtBox.InputScope = new InputScope { Names = { new InputScopeName { NameValue = InputScopeNameValue.Text } } };
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not really sure what you want from this, if all you want is to make it more readable, then a few well placed new-lines will make a world of difference. If you want to reduce the amount of code, I don't think there is much room for that other than switching constructors for `InputScopeName`.

```
txtBox.InputScope = new InputScope
{
    Names =
    {
        new InputScopeName(InputScopeNameValue.Text)
    }
};
```

Note: `Text` does not appear to be a [valid member](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.inputscopenamevalue.aspx) of `InputScopeNameValue`, but ill keep it for the sake of consistency with the question.